# How to open multiple pages after login a website using puppeteer automation?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, session-cookies

I am trying to scrape a website that requires authentication. I am using node.js and puppeteer. I know this requires a cookie to save and then use this cookie multiple times until it expires.I wrote the code that is given below.
**What this code is doing?**

it open the login page....login in successfully and saved the session in the local file, but not doing further work(to open another page on the same website that requires authentication). What can be the problem?

**code**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cookiesFilePath = 'cookies.json';
const cheerio=require('cheerio');
const fs = require("fs");


exports.scrapper=async ()=>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
      });
    
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setDefaultTimeout(100000)
    await page.goto('https://www.rasmussenreports.com/login');
    
    await page.click('#username');
    await page.type('input','MY_USERNAME',{delay:100})
    
    await page.click('#password');
    await page.type('input','MY_PASSWORD',{delay:100});
    
    await page.click('form > fieldset > div > div.form-group.col-md-2.align-self-end.text-center > button');
    
    // wait till page load
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    
    //store cookie
    const cookiesObject = await page.cookies()
    
    fs.writeFile(cookiesFilePath, JSON.stringify(cookiesObject),
    function(err) { 
    if (err) {
    console.log('The file could not be written.', err)
    }
     console.log('Session has been successfully saved')
    });

    await page.waitForNavigation();


            
//open new page
    // const expage = await browser.newPage();

    const cookieString=await fs.readFileSync(cookiesFilePath);
    const cookies=JSON.parse(cookieString);
    await page.setCookie(...cookies)

    await page.goto('https://www.rasmussenreports.com/public_content/politics/general_politics/august_2022/inflation_crime_still_top_concerns_for_voters');

        console.log("opened");

await browser.close();
}
```

Comment: Hard to help since the problem is behind a login, but generally you want to use `Promise.all` to avoid a race condition between `waitForNavigation` and the navigiation trigger `click`. Throwing random `waitForNavigation`s around will generally time out. Make sure you're sure you need those.

Comment: Thanks bro...i used try catch now...and the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

This might happens because the navigation might happen on login before you wait for it.

Ideally, You'll need to `waitForNavigation` at the same time while clicking on the login button.

```js
await Promise.all([page.click("LOGIN_SELECTOR"), page.waitForNavigation()]);
```

Also, If you want to speed it up, You can open multiple tabs after doing the login:

```js
// Login & authentication 
...
// Open another tab
const tab = browser.newPage();

// Open another tab
const tab1 = browser.newPage();

...
```